# how to make window auto scrolling using css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have a design that is similar to this image[image]

the red color is another div I want the window to auto scroll when hover over that little red part of the div so it go down till the whole div is shown so it should look like this

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Can't do that with CSS

Comment: Use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: May I just add that scroll jacking, as it is called, is one of the most infuriating things ever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scroll').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $("body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 500);
  })
})
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: #f00;
}
.green {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
.red,
.green {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red scroll"></div>
<div class="green scroll"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't scroll the window using CSS only.

Use javascript and the [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method.

Simple demo

```js
document.querySelector('[data-scrollintoview]').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  e.target.scrollIntoView(true);
});
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 150px;
}
.red {
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="black"></div>
<div data-scrollintoview class="red"></div>
```